# How to cut .ogg video files using command prompt?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

ogg video files using command prompt. I tried to use ffmpeg and it's working for mp4 files. When I want to run command like this for .ogg file:

```
ffmpeg -i C:\Users\Jarek\Desktop\camspot_rec\rec1.ogg -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 0:00:05 C:\Users\Jarek\Desktop\camspot_rec\rec5.ogg
```

I get an error: "Could not write header for output file #0 : Invaid data found when processing input."

Is it possible to cut .ogg file using command prompt? I need it becouse I have to save streams from 4 cameras to files and later I have to cut them in order to synchronize them.

Here is my code to save files from streams:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("rtsp://");
    axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("rtsp://");
    axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("rtsp://");
    axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("rtsp://");

    axVLCPlugin21.playlist.play();
    Process.Start("C://Program Files//VideoLAN//VLC//VLC.exe", "\"rtsp://" --qt-start-minimized --sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,acodec=flac,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:file{dst=C:\\Users\\Jarek\\Desktop\\camspot_rec\\rec1.ogg,no-overwrite}");
    Process.Start("C://Program Files//VideoLAN//VLC//VLC.exe", "\"rtsp://" --qt-start-minimized --sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,acodec=flac,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:file{dst=C:\\Users\\Jarek\\Desktop\\camspot_rec\\rec2.ogg,no-overwrite}");
    Process.Start("C://Program Files//VideoLAN//VLC//VLC.exe", "\"rtsp://" --qt-start-minimized --sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,acodec=flac,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:file{dst=C:\\Users\\Jarek\\Desktop\\camspot_rec\\rec3.ogg,no-overwrite}");
    Process.Start("C://Program Files//VideoLAN//VLC//VLC.exe", "\"rtsp://" --qt-start-minimized --sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,acodec=flac,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:file{dst=C:\\Users\\Jarek\\Desktop\\camspot_rec\\rec4.ogg,no-overwrite}");
}
```

And I would like to do something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("vlc"))
            {
                process.Kill();
            }
            Process.Start("ffmpeg -i C:\\Users\\Jarek\\Desktop\\camspot_rec\\rec1.ogg -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 0:00:05 C:\\Users\\Jarek\\Desktop\\camspot_rec\\rec5.avi");
        }
```

Comment: This seems purely a ffmpeg question not a c# question.. as the question seems to be how to split it using the ffmpeg utility not c#

Comment: You're right, I corrected the tag. Thanks :)

Comment: Show the full console output for the failed command.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/UkOGe

Comment: It's not detecting the video stream. Does this happen with all the files? Since you created these with VLC, open it there and rewrap to Matroska MKV. Then you can try cutting with FFmpeg.

Comment: I have changed output for .avi and it works, but I have to open this files by VLC media player, becouse other programs are not able to do it. Now I have a little problem because when I save file.avi or even file.ogg I can't see video duration...